# Highcharts crosshair labels going backwards when hovering

Tags: highcharts

I have a highcharts chart in the below fiddle that has a problem with the xAxis crosshairs. If you run your cursor over the chart from the start of the xAxis the crosshair works correctly and displays the date at the bottom of the chart.

When you get half way however the crosshair label starts going backwards, even though it shows the correct date.

I don;t like jumping to conclusions about bugs in commerical products, bnut I can't help thinking that this is one - has anybody got any ideas?

https://jsfiddle.net/LiamFlavelle/sgkd0v7n/5/

```
This is an empty code block because I need to add a jsfiddle but the options data is too big!
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's a bug. However, that has already been reported and fixed on our GitHub page here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/20856

The fix will be included with the next Highcharts release.

Comment: Any idea when that will be?

Comment: Couple of weeks from now, but no strict date yet since we just had a release recently.